# Is it possible to match wordlists in an accent-insensitive way?

Tags: uima, ruta

I would like to match place names in French documents. I tried to use MARKFAST, but I'm faced with the problem of accents sensitivity. Assume my `places.txt` file contains "`Uzès`". My RUTA rule is as follows:

```
PACKAGE my.example;
DECLARE PlaceName;
WORDLIST PlaceNamesList = "places.txt";

Document{ -> MARKFAST(PlaceName, PlaceNamesList, true)};
```

The rule correctly matches *Uzès* in the text, *uzès* or even *UZÈS* but not *UZES* nor *Uzes*, which are forms I expect to find in my texts.

What is the correct solution to achieve this? Do I have to generate unaccented versions of all place names? (which does not completely solve my problem, I also expect variation on accentuation in texts, such as in *Uzés*). Do other RUTA resources (word tables, MTWL) perform differently on accents?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, UIMA Ruta (currently 2.5.0) does not support accent-insensitive matching.

You either need to (programmatically) expand your wordlists, or use a different annotator.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid there are currently no accent-insensitive dictionary annotators. I will build one and package it as a UimaFit component, in order to be able to include it as Ruta "preprocessing".